In Spades, with the mercy rule, what happens if both teams get a score under -200?
In Spades, the mercy rule: if you go below -200 you lose.
What happens if both teams go below -200 at the same time?
For example, in the first hand, both partnerships bid 8 and NIL and neither partner makes the bid, the next hand both partners go nil on one team, and the other team goes 13 and again, neither team makes their bids.

If both partnerships got under -200, then the partnership that has lower score losses.  If both partnerships has exactly the same score then its a draw.
In your example, on the first hand both partnership got -180 and on the second hand the first partnership got -200 and the second partnership got -130. In this case the first partnership loses due to score of -380 which is lower than the -310 of the second partnership.
